# Qubits from fermions?

Tags: quantum-information, fermions, quantum-computer, bosons, quantum-statistics

I'm confused about qubits and fermions/bosons. I would like to look at a specific example:

Take an electron (which is a fermion) with its spins as a qubit system. A spin up state is the $\lvert 0 \rangle$ state, and a spin down state is the $\lvert 1 \rangle$ state. If I want a two qubits state, for example $\lvert 00 \rangle$, can I take two electrons in the spin up state and put them side by side? However, if I do that, do I need to antisymmetrize the wavefunction, i.e. $\lvert0\rangle_A \lvert0\rangle_B - \lvert0\rangle_B\lvert0\rangle_A$, where $A$ and $B$ are the labels of the two electrons. (I'm ignoring the normalisation as it is not the point of this question.) If I do the antisymmetrization, then I do not get the $\lvert 0 \rangle_A \lvert0 \rangle_B$ state... I'm confused here... What is going on?

Comment: The ket notation you use above is highly misleading. This looks like second quantization, with A, B denoting modes rather than particls, in which case there is no need to antisymmetrize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to antisymmetrize the wavefunction unless you put both electrons into the same trap. If you set up two traps, each with one electron in it, then the $\lvert 0\rangle_1$ state in one trap is distinct from the $\lvert 0\rangle_2$ state in the other, so Pauli exclusion is irrelevant since neither of the electrons can occupy a state the other can also occupy.

Comment: I don't understand why we don't have to antisymmetrize the wavefunction. Is it because the electrons can now be distinguished?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the spins of electron 1 and electron 2 as qubits.  What you do is that qubit 1 is the spin of the electron in trap 1, and qubit 2 is the spin of the electron in trap 2.  You still need to antisymmetrize your state -- at least in principle -- i.e., the overall state is

> (electron 1 in trap 1, in state 1)(electron 2 in trap 2, in state 2) - (electron 1 in trap 2, in state 2)(electron 2 in trap 1, in state 1)

However, you will observe that it is clear which qubit is found in which trap.